# Perl: How to reliably shell_quote filenames with UTF8

Tags: macos, perl

I need to check for the existance of some file that may

- contain whitespaces in its name
- contain non-ASCII (e.g., Umlauts) in its name

Because of the whitespaces I use `String::ShellQuote`. This, however, seems to not work well with the Umlauts when executed on OSX (don't know yet about other OS):

```
    # vim: ft=perl fenc=utf8
    # perl 5, version 12, subversion 4 (v5.12.4) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level

    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use String::ShellQuote;

    my @files = map {$_, shell_quote($_)} ("AOU.tmp", "ÄÖÜ.tmp", "A OU.tmp", "Ä ÖU.tmp");
    foreach my $file ( @files, ) {
        print "$file:\t";
        `touch $file`;
        print "created, " if( !$? ) ;
        print "EXISTS (says Perl), " if( -e $file );
        `ls -1 $file >/dev/null`;
        print "EXISTS (says ls), " if( !$? );
        print "\n";
    }
```

Output:

```
    OU.tmp:     created, EXISTS (says Perl), EXISTS (says ls), 
    AOU.tmp:    created, EXISTS (says Perl), EXISTS (says ls), 
    ÄÖÜ.tmp:    created, EXISTS (says Perl), EXISTS (says ls), 
    'ÄÖÜ.tmp':  created, EXISTS (says ls), 
    A OU.tmp:   created, EXISTS (says Perl), EXISTS (says ls), 
    'A OU.tmp': created, EXISTS (says ls), 
    Ä ÖU.tmp:   created, EXISTS (says Perl), EXISTS (says ls), 
    'Ä ÖU.tmp': created, EXISTS (says ls),
```

**Question: How can I reliably shell_quote filenames that may contain extended characters?**

*Side note: I assume this is one of these totally great OS-X typical UTF8 normalization issues (precomposed vs. decomposed encoding of Umlauts). Nevertheless, I think that `String::ShellQuote` should be able to deal with it.*

Comment: "Just don't use [spaces|umlauts|...] in file names!"     (This comment would show up for sure, so I just added it already...)

Comment: everything is valid in a filename except for `\0` and `/`. Code should always handle all of it. Stop using shell code in perl.

Comment: @jordanm: On OSX is, depending on the API level, even `/` allowed in a file name ... (and transparently transformed to `:` in the file system and vice versa). Shell hint taken, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the bugs are all yours.

Let's run through the two loops for `A OU.tmp`:

First, the unquoted form.

1. You print `A OU.tmp`
2. You run `touch A OU.tmp`.  This creates (or updates) two files `A` and `OU.tmp`
3. Touch ran successfully, so you print "created, "
4. You check `-e "A OU.tmp"`.  There is no such file (I believe you've mis-transcribed your output, because it is not what I get when I paste in your code running perl 5, version 12, subversion 4 (v5.12.4) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level)
5. You run `ls A OU.tmp`.  This is roughly equivalent to running `ls A && ls OU.tmp`.  Both these files exist, so the command succeeds.
6. Since it worked, you print "EXISTS (says ls), "

Next time through the loop, Shell_Quote makes `$file` be equal to `'A OU.tmp'`

1. You print `'A OU.tmp'`
2. You run `touch 'A OU.tmp'`.  This creates (or updates) a single file, named `A OU.tmp` (because the space was quoted)
3. Touch ran successfully, so you print "created, "
4. You check `-e "'A OU.tmp'"`  There is no such file.  There is a file named `A OU.tmp`, but no file named `'A OU.tmp'` which is what you're asking Perl to look for.  (Perl is not your shell, so if you give Perl shell-quoted things, it's not going to interpret them like the shell.
5. You run `ls 'A OU.tmp'`.  This checks for a single file with a space in its name, which exists, so the command succeeds.
6. Since it worked, you print "EXISTS (says ls), "

The central problem seems to be that you're treating Perl like a thin layer over the shell.  You should generally choose to work with files *either* in Perl *or* in the shell.

In Perl:

```
# do not use Shell_Quote
foreach my $file ( @files, ) {
    open my $FH, ">>$file" or die;
    close $FH;
    print "yep!" if (-e $file);
}
```

In shell (via Perl):

```
# use only Shell_Quote
foreach my $file ( @files, ) {
    `touch $file`;
    print "yes!" if (`ls $file`);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Nathaniel. (I fell pretty ashamed about not having looked up the files that actually got created...)

Comment: There's no need to `open` and `close` the file to test for file existence

Comment: *"Perl is not your shell, so if you give Perl shell-quoted things, it's not going to interpret them like the shell"* This actually was (aside my bugs) the missing information! (a) I was not aware that Perl's internal functions could not deal with quoted filenames. (b) I didn't notice that `shell_quote` does not quote `AOU`, but *does* quote `ÄÖÜ`, which explains the different handling by `-e`.

Comment: @Zaid Correct.  I was opening the file in append mode as an approximation of the behavior of `touch`: it creates the file if it doesn't exist, and updates the timestamp without altering the contents if the file already exists.  (I'm not sure that that's all defined behavior, but it works on all of my machines.)

Comment: @Daniel "can't deal with quoted filenames" isn't how I'd put it.  Rather, I'd say that Perl has no need to escape filenames.  Once you have a string in a scalar variable, Perl can use that exact string as a file name without any further effort on your part.  So if you give Perl a string that is literally `''""''""` it has no problem making a file with that name.  If you tried that in a shell, it'd be hellish (as is, that's an empty string to the shell).